# Adobe Premiere Elements 12 hangs on Loading ExporterQuicktimeHost.prm on startup

Tags: windows-7, adobe-premiere, photoshop-elements

I'm running Adobe Premiere Elements 12 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, and recently it started hanging on startup showing `Loading ExporterQuicktimeHost.prm`.

This behaviour has started recently (it was working fine until at least January), with no changes to Premiere Elements since then (I suppose it was caused by some windows update).

According to Adobe's own instructions, I tried (without any success):

- reinstalling quicktime and Premiere Elements
- uninstalling all 3rd party codecs
- making sure "Adobe QT32 Server.exe", "dynamiclinkmanager.exe" and "adobe premiere elements.exe" were whitelisted on the firewall

I found that killing the `dynamiclinkmanager.exe` process when the startup is stuck unblocks Premiere Elements, but it has to be done every time I start it.

What is the problem here? Is there a permanent solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try following:
While opening Premiere and when it hangs on QT32 server, try to kill process in task manager and kill premiere process, then check if the QT process is down and also check if Dynamic link process is down. If they are just restart Premiere.

If the QT process can not be stopped then you have the problem with your firewall software. There are some third party firewall apps which can cause QT server to fail to instantiate, for instance Comodo firewall for sure I had bad experience with it.

Also there is one more possibility that you added some new codecs which conflict with the old ones especially concerning quick time like for instance DNXHD QT codecs or similar from Avid.

These info can not be found on Adobe or at least I have not found it there.

Hope this will work for you or at least give you idea how to find the solution.

Best wishes

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -1):

I have a clean install, and this problem happens to me when Premiere hangs and crashes.

While Premiere is stuck at the splash screen, go to Task Manager and kills the "Adobe QT32 Server.exe" process. Now, it'll open gracefully, but I advise you to restart it!